# Integration of $\int_{x_l}^{x_r} \frac{1}{1+e^y (a-x)^b} dx$

Tags: integration

I need help on this integration. I tried with **substitution rules and integration by part**, however it is not work. It gave me LHS=RHS. Anyone have idea on how to solve it? I even tried with partial fraction, but the value of $b>0$ can be any positive real number therefore this method could not be applied to my problem.

Comment: Are *x* and *y* independent variables ?

Comment: $x$ is variable, $y$ and $b$ are parameters where $y$ can be any real number and $b$ is positive real number. Hope I answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not seem (at least, to me !) to be an easy problem.

Let us consider $$I=\int \frac{dx}{1+e^y (a-x)^b}$$ and make the change of variable $$x=a-z e^{-\frac{y}{b}}$$ This leads to $$I=- e^{-\frac{y}{b}} \int \frac{dz}{1+z^b}$$ and $$J=\int \frac{dz}{1+z^b}=z \,\, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{b};1+\frac{1}{b};-z^b\right)$$ where appears the hypergeometric function which can be made explicit for integer (and may be some rational) values of $b$ but which could be very difficult to make explicit for the most general case where $b$ would just be a real number.

Comment: Thank you sir. For the $J$, may I know any source I can refer to for working steps?

Comment: You are very welcome ! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html